# Django - Is there a way to display a fa icon in a Django ChoiceField?

Tags: django, django-views

In my page, I have a notification system, which allows the admins to send custom notifications to a certain set of users. For now, it works correctly, creating a Notification object, which is then displayed to the users that need to see it.

In my notifications bar in the UI, it displays a list of notifications, ordered by date, and each notification has an icon. For specific notifications (system-level notifications), there's specific fa icons being included `<i class="fas fa-handshake"></i>`, for instance.

I'd like the admins to be able to include a specific icon from a set of icons I set. My relevant models look like this:

```
class Icono(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return mark_safe('<i class="{}"></i>'.format(self.slug))
```

```
class Notificacion(models.Model):
    icono = models.ForeignKey(Icono, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    # Other attributes
```

I have a CreateView that creates the notification, that looks like this:

```
class FormEnviarNotificacionView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, SetUserEventoFormMixin, CreateView):
    model = Notificacion
    form_class = NotificacionForm
    template_name = 'eventos_admin/enviar_notificacion_a_asistentes.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('eventos_admin:send_notification', kwargs={'pk_evento': self.request.user.evento_activo.id})

    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        if not self.object:
            return messages.warning(self.request, 'Hubo un error al enviar la notificación. Por favor, sólo envíe texto.')
        return 'Mensaje enviado correctamente.'
```

And the form is just this:

```
class NotificacionForm(AgregarNotificacionMixin, forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Notificacion
        fields = ['mensaje', 'url', 'icono']
```

It doesn't have to be with that method or something equivalent, if you know of a library or widget that does something similar, I'd be okay with looking it up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: Add extra attributes to form fields generated by UpdateView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52789976/django-add-extra-attributes-to-form-fields-generated-by-updateview)

Comment: Not really, I know how to change the widgets of fields, but I guess my solution would be either I'm missing something so I can display an "<i>" html tag inside of a Django ChoiceField, or, alternatively, know if there is a widget that can handle that, but the issue wouldn't be how to use it, but which could be useful for this.